# Could a type sensitive language be typeless?

Tags: java, c++, types

Why is it not possible to make Java or C++ typeless ?
int, float, double etc any type could inherit from a basetype, but why is this not
possible or not applied ?
I could imagine a Java-"typeless" function like this

```
void some(BASETYPE anyobject, BASENUMERIC a_number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < int(a_number); i ++) {
        anyobject.doStuff(i);
    }
}
```

where `int` inherits from BASENUMERIC.

**Edit**
Sorry for the confusion. What a mean is not a *real* typelessness, but if any type inherits from a base type, polymorphism allows me to make a function be callable with any object, but at the same time I was able to
define a specific type.

```
void any(BASETYPE of_any_type, float a_must_be_float) {
    ...
```

Hopefully you can understand my intention better now.

Comment: C++ is a strongly typed language. Even template code resolves to specific types at compile time. Perhaps you'd prefer Smalltalk?

Comment: Are you suggesting that 'BASETYPE' isn't a type?

Comment: I don't see how this would fit any imaginable interpretation of the term "typeless". You're asking why Java and C++ have primitive types instead of making everything including `int`, `double` etc. be objects as well, right? That's called a [unified type system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233112/what-is-an-unified-type-system).

Comment: ???? I didn't understand your idea...

Comment: Java's "BASETYPE" is [`Object`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) and "BASENUMERIC" would be [`Number`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)

Comment: You can do the following in Java which is almost the same. `void some(Object o, Number n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n.intValue(); i ++) {
        o.getClass().getMethod("doStuff", int.class).invoke(o, i);
    }
}`

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. Well I ment not *really* typeless like Python, but if all types would inherit from a basetype, I could wouls have the ability to specify types need for calling a function but I'd also have the ability to let the user decide what type instance he overloads to the function.

Comment: @Peter Interesting, I must try this out. So Object is the Superclass of **any** other type ?

Comment: You can only do this in C++ with objects; int is a primitive type and cannot by used in this way :/

Comment: @Niklas, Object is a super type of any regular class. In Java, the primitive types are autoboxed with a wrapper so they will work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly because type-safety is a good thing. It prevents you from calling floating-point functions with characters. It's not a problem; it's a feature which prevents you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: What he proposes (or at least, how I understood it) wouldn't mean you can call `float f(float)` with a `char` but `object f(object)` with a `char` (without autoboxing).

Comment: @delnan: This is what I mean. Dave: Yes, as clarified above, I don't want *real* typelessness, I still want to define types, but everythinh should inheritnfrom a base type.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is slower and possibly error prone to have all these implicit conversions. You can if you want to, by the way. If you use variant-like types (I don't know if this exists in Java), you can assign a variable of any type to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can already do this is C++, using templates

```
template<typename BASETYPE, typename BASENUMERIC>
void some(BASETYPE anyobject, BASENUMERIC a_number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < int(a_number); i ++) {
        anyobject.doStuff(i);
    }
}
```

Works for any BASETYPE having a dostuff member function and type BASENUMERIC convertible to int.

Comment: Not really, this generates a different function for each use, which shows its ugly face in several cases, such as the need to have the definition available everywhere you use it.

Comment: And a typeless C++ would not? :-)

Comment: A "typeless" (I still think that's a horrible term, especially for what OP is talking about) would allow a non-templated function like this for some typedefs `BASETYPE` and `BASENUMERIC`.