# Why do unboxed types have methods?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, types, boxing

Why can you do things like

```
int i = 10;
i.ToString();
'c'.Equals('d');
1.ToString();
true.GetType();
```

in C#? Those things right there are either primitive, literal, unboxed, or any combination of those things; so why do they have methods? **They are not objects** and so should not have methods. Is this syntax sugar for something else? If so, what? I can understand having functions that do these things, for example:

```
string ToString(int number)
{
  // Do mad code
  return newString;
}
```

but in that case you would call it as a function, not a method:

```
string ranch = ToString(1);
```

What's going on here?

edit:

Just realised C# isn't a java clone anymore and the rules are totally different. oops :P

Comment: You mean "why do [structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saxz13w4.aspx) have methods"? It's because they just do. (And *thankfully!*, ever use Java?) Also, *every structure extends object* (implicitly), even though it might be (really, often is) treated as a "value type".

Comment: Unified Type System: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233112/what-is-an-unified-type-system

Comment: Of course they are objects! Value types are objects that inherit from System.Object, and by definition of "inheritance", have all the methods of their base class. Why do you believe that value types are not objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They act like that because the spec says so (and it's pretty nice) :

> ### 1.28 Value types
>
> A value type is either a struct type or an enumeration type. C# provides a set of predefined struct types called the simple types.
>   The simple types are identified through reserved words.

...

> ### 1.28.4 Simple types
>
> C# provides a set of predefined struct types called the simple types.
>   The simple types are identified through reserved words, but these
>   reserved words are simply aliases for predefined struct types in the
>   System namespace, as described in the table below.

...

> Because a simple type aliases a struct type, every simple type has
>   members. For example, int has the members declared in System.Int32 and
>   the members inherited from System.Object, and the following statements
>   are permitted:
>
> ```
> int i = int.MaxValue; // System.Int32.MaxValue constant
> string s = i.ToString(); // System.Int32.ToString() instance method
> string t = 123.ToString(); // System.Int32.ToString() instance method
> ```
>
> The simple types differ from other struct types in that they permit
>   certain additional operations:
>
> Most simple types permit values to be created by writing literals
>   (§1.16.4). For example, 123 is a literal of type int and 'a' is a
>   literal of type char. C# makes no provision for literals of struct
>   types in general, and nondefault values of other struct types are
>   ultimately always created through instance constructors of those
>   struct types.

As the spec explains simple types have some **super powers** like the ability to be `const`, a special literal syntax that could be used instead of new, and the capacity to be computed at compilation time (2+2 is actually written as 4 in the final MSIL stream)

But methods (as well as operators) aren't a special super powers and all structs could have them.

The specification (for C# 4.0, my copy paste is from an earlier version) could be downloaded from the microsoft website : [C# Language Specification 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029)

Answer (score 6):

Eric Lippert's recent article [Inheritance and Representation](http://ericlippert.com/2011/09/19/inheritance-and-representation/) explains.(Spoiler: You are confusing inheritance and representation.)

Not sure why you claim that the integer `i`, the character `'c'` and the integer `1` are not objects. They are.

Comment: They aren't (well, they are in the C meaning of the word, but that's not what we mean in OO code), but they can be treated as objects when it's convenient to do so.

Comment: They are objects. See VirtualBlackFox's reply, where the spec says "For example, int has the members declared in System.Int32 and the members inherited from System.Object." `int` inherits from `System.Object`. See Eric's article for further discussion.

Comment: Look at the IL for `int i = 1` and you'll see that 32 bit integer being pushed onto the stack. If the primitives were objects, what are the objects implemented with?

Comment: Jon: but that's a compiler optimization. By the time it's IL we aren't speaking c# anymore

Comment: @Jon Hanna: Structs (And simple types ARE structs) are objects, the "struct" keyword denote a value type (enum too, and nullable versions of them are also value types) and this add some semantics (copy-on-assign, boxing, unboxing, cannot have the special value null without nullable) but it's still an object. What they aren't are reference types (They inherit from one, "System.Object", but aren't reference types) but you could box them into one.

Comment: @Jon - how do you explain the result of `typeof(int).BaseType.BaseType`?

Comment: How do you explain their memory layout?

Comment: You are confusing inheritance with representation. There is no requirement that a derived class share memory representation with the base class.

Comment: @JulienRoncaglia: The ECMA spec http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf says in section I.8.9.7 that value-type storage locations aren't objects; for each value type there exists an object type, and storage locations of the value type may be boxed to yield a reference to an instance of that object type, but a value-type storage location holds neither an object of the type in question nor a reference to one.

Comment: @supercat: You're doing the same error as Eric & Raymond are pointing to others, you are confusing the language (C#) where value types are Objects and the CLI that is a common specification of one possible VM to implement the language. Structs are designed as they are to permit such optimizations and allow a conforming implementation to avoid the different costs associated with reference types (GC handling & v-table) most of the time. But even if it was designed to allow this specific optimization; from the C# point of view what the CLI is specifying is an implementation detail.

Comment: @JulienRoncaglia: Even if the C# spec declares that a storage location of type `Int32` holds an object, neither the storage location nor its contents behaves in the manner of anything the ECMA spec calls an "object".  Even if the authors of the C# spec would like to use the same terminology for "object" and "thing which is has an implicit non-identity-preserving conversion to object", the two are not the same.  I would suggest that if something is an object that implements `IEnumerator<Int32>`, then it should be possible for a reference of type `IEnumerator<Int32>` to identify it.

Comment: @JulienRoncaglia: Although there exists an implicit non-identity-preserving conversion from `List<Int32>.Enumerator` to `IEnumerator<Int32>`, that does not make it possible for a reference of type `IEnumerator<Int32>` to identify a storage location of type `List<Int32>.Enumerator` nor the direct contents thereof.  The fact that reference types and value types have different semantics is useful; that the authors of the C# spec define a cats as ducks doesn't make non-quacking cats defective.

Answer (score 2):

In C# all primitive types are actually structures.

Comment: -1 the problem with this answer is that "primitive types" aren't well defined. You could be right or wrong. For example a string is often considered a primitive and its definitely not a structure. It also does nothing to help clear up the OP's confusion

Answer (score 0):

So that you can use them!

It's convenient to be able to do so, so you can.

Now, in order to do so, primitives can be treated as structs. E.g. a 32-bit integer can be processed as a 32-bit integer, but it can also be processed as `public struct Int32 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<int>, IEquatable<int>`. We mostly get the best of both worlds.