# Where can i find a tree chart of C#'s Unified Type System?

Tags: c#

I tried looking all over the internet. I found some in google images, but they're not complete. I've seen some overview of Unified Type Systems, but they don't have a chart of it. Do you know any links?

Comment: What do you mean "they are not complete". The chart can't obviously show _every_ type there is, can it?

Comment: really? I'm new to C# so I didn't know that. Is there a chart that at least shows the Object, Class, Interface, Delegate, String, Array, Struct, Enum, Decimal, Int, Double, Float, Char, Bool?

Comment: [Asking for off-site resources if Off-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unified type system basically means ([almost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234509/5133585)) every type in C# is compatible with `System.Object`. Everything is a subtype of that.

Among the list of things you listed, class, interface, and struct aren't really types, they are types of types. I can say that `System.Int32` (`int`) is a struct, but it actually inherits from `System.ValueType`, which inherits from `System.Object`.

Anyway, here's the best I can do:

- `System.Object`

  - `System.ValueType`

    - `System.Enum`

      - All enums
    - `System.Int32` (`int`)
    - `System.Decimal`
    - `System.Single` (`float`)
    - `System.Double`
    - `System.Char`
    - `System.Boolean` (`bool`)
    - All structs
  - `System.Delegate`

    - All delegates
  - `System.String`
  - `System.Array`
  - All classes and interfaces

Comment: This is what I'm actually looking for.